# Intrinsic Content Size vs Alignment Rect

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit

When would you need to override alignmentRect instead of intrinsicContentSize in some UIView subclass?

Is it just for when the position as well as the size is different? If you supply an alignmentRect, is the content size ignored?

Answer (score 1):

`intrinsicContentSize` is used to tell the layout system what the size of a view is. Use this to inform the layout system how large to draw a view based on its contents. Content size, not position.

For positioning, there are two things you should look at:

`layoutMargins`, which is used to determine the layout of the inside of a view (i.e. padding on the left and right of a `stackView`'s contents), and `alignmentRectInsets`, which is used to inform the object holding your view how it should align your view. For example, if you have a shadow or attached view (like a notification dot), you might want to lay your view out centered on the primary feature, not including the shadow or dot's width/height.

The article [Auto Layout in iOS 8 - Layout Margins](https://carpeaqua.com/2014/07/24/auto-layout-in-ios-8-layout-margins/) at *Carpeaqua* does a good job of explaining layout margins with examples, and the article [Auto Layout and Alignment Rectangles](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/auto-layout-and-alignment-rectangles/) at *Use Your Loaf* does a good job of explaining and showing why you might want to use an `alignmentRectInsets`.